# Understanding complex curl command that uses oauth

Tags: node.js, curl, oauth

I have the following curl command (company specific details removed):

```
curl -v -u "user:password" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 
"grant_type=annonymised:mycompany:params:oauth:grant-type:apiKey&apikey=myAPI Key" 
"myendpoint goes here"
```

I am new to CURL and am trying to convert this into a request using nodejs 'request' module (bear in mind I'm actually using username/password rather than API Key). What do I put in the 'form' parameter? At the moment I have:

```
form: { "params": "oauth","grant_type": "password", "username": username, "password": password },
```

but as I can't read the above curl request, I'm struggling to know whats missing (I repeat, I'm using username/password and not API key). Can anyone help with this please.

Comment: Have you tried `curl -u user:password` ?

Comment: They are not the real username/password. My question is how to read the curl command and specifically, what to put in the 'form' object(my incorrect attempt is in the question). I'm not sure how you've answered my question... Specifically, how to convert from 'grant-type =' into the 'form' part of the request

Comment: I'm looking for an understanding of how to read the curl with the goal of knowing what to put in the 'form' part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `curl` command will:

- use [HTTP Basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) with username `user` and password `password`
- to `POST` a form (header field `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`)
- with two parameters URL-encoded in the request's body:

  - `grant_type` parameter is set to value `annonymised:mycompany:params:oauth:grant-type:apiKey`
  - and `apikey` param is set to `myAPI Key`
- to the URL endpoint you called `myendpoint goes here`.

Using the [`request` module](https://github.com/request/request) in `node.js`, based on the [example for HTTP Auth](https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication) and [form posting](https://github.com/request/request#forms), the `node.js` equivalent would look like:

```
var request = require('request');

request.post('myendpoint goes here').auth('user', 'password').form({
    grant_type: 'annonymised:mycompany:params:oauth:grant-type:apiKey',
    apikey: 'myAPI Key'
});
```

Comment: Cool, let me know how it goes.

Comment: That was a very helpful explanation-thank you. I got it to work one I found the right parameters in our documentation...

Comment: You're welcome, and I'm glad to help. But, the nicest way to thank someone on StackOverflow for a helpful answer is to [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it. It also helps others that come by later in search of an answer to their problem, by providing cues that some answer is helpful (even before reading it). I see on your profile you don't really vote much (up, or down), but you really should. It costs you nothing, and it helps others.